# Where are the Zalenium log files stored

Tags: zalenium

We have max-tests set to 1 so that each test case should be getting a brand new container. However, we are seeing that used containers are not being destroyed consistently.

Therefore I am asking where can I see any errors from Zalenium itself?

I see there are options for LogBack config, but what is the default location for any log file?

Comment: Please add more details such as the env, version, configurations details if any.

Answer (score 0):

The plain vanilla install on Ubuntu
Im assuming the Zalenium container is creating logs on that container
Im just asking where is the default location for these?
Thanks